# Refer to an Array VBA

Tags: vba

When calling a function of a DLL in VBA, VBA stops running. The function expects an array and an integer, but when I debug the program, the function does not work.

The DLL is made by someone else, the information of the DLL is available.

```
Declare Function loadModel Lib "Test.dll" (ByVal numArgs As Integer, args As String) As Integer

  filename = "Tjet.mxl"
  ArgumentList(0) = "Filename:"
  ArgumentList(1) = filename
  ArgumentList(2) = "Show model:"
  ArgumentList(3) = False
  ArgumentList(4) = "Show Progress"
  ArgumentList(5) = True

  model = loadModel(6, ArgumentList(0))
```

However, this does not work. How do you refer to an Array in vba?

---

The Delphi code of the DLL is:

```
TdLoadModel = function(numArgs: Integer; args: PPAnsiChar): Integer; cdecl

loadModel : TdLoadModel

// loadmodel
SetLength(ArgumentList, 6); //will create an array of 3 AnsiStrings
ArgumentList[0]:='-filename';
ArgumentList[1]:='TJET.mxl';
ArgumentList[2]:='-showModel';
ArgumentList[3]:='false';
ArgumentList[4]:='-showProgress';
ArgumentList[5]:='true';
PArgumentsList := @ArgumentList[0];
loadModel(6, PArgumentsList);
```

When I join the arguments, I still got some errors. I send the errors to the maker of the program and the DLL, but I am still waiting for an answer.
My question is: Expects the DLL indeed an array, or is my expectation wrong?

Comment: how do you know that the `.dll` is expecting an array? You said: *`The function expects an array and an integer`* but your declaration seems in the wrong order plus you are passing single variables `Integer` and `String` and not an array which I believe should be `args() as String`

Answer (score 0):

The function does not expect an array of `String`s but rather a single `String`. You should `Join` your `ArgumentList` (assuming that is correctly declared)

```
model = loadModel(6, Join(ArgumentList))
```

Comment: How do you know it expects a string of space-delimited arguments?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett One knows that the function expects a `String` from the declaration. One guesses that the argument list is most probably space-delimited because: 1) is a general practice in most library functions and command interpreters, 2) is the default for `Join`.